# Backup Android Eclipse Project

Tags: android, backup, project

How do I back up my Android project in Eclipse?

Simply just copy the folder of the workspace? or have a tool to create backup and import backup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally do `Export --> Archive File` in Eclipse. This creates a Zip/Tar of (one or more) Eclipse projects, which can simply be imported into another Eclipse Workspace (via `Import --> Existing Projects into Workspace` and then `Select Archive File`)

Comment: The problem with this is that, though you can filter what is archived in various ways (so that you aren't backing up bins and libs for instance), you have to configure that every time.  There is no way - that I can see - to setup a filter of some sort and then apply that filter each time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know backup facility in eclipse IDE. I am using Tortoise SVN for creating backup in my system. If you are interested to use it, i will explain, otherwise ignore it.

Comment: I am interested in knowing this SVN.
What does he do? What he has to do with Android and Eclipse?
I would like an explanation about the program and how it works, thanks for the tip

Comment: [Check this link, it is good tutorial about using Tortoise SVN in Windows](http://www.shokhirev.com/nikolai/programs/SVN/svn.html)